# Router Transformation

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a question about router TF, I have  3 groups as **A** ,**B**, **C** If incoming records satisfy **A group** and **B group** condition, in which group the record is going to be stored?

Answer (score 1):

A record that satisfies multiple conditions will be routed to **multiple output groups**.